# 7 Years for Magento

Tags: discussion

[Magento](http://magento.com/) launched on March 31, 2008.It means today we are in 7th year now lets gather all the features and many interesting things about [Magento.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Happy Birthday, Magento!

Comment: Happy Birthday for  magento developer

Comment: Happy birthday Magento. Good reason to order cake... with the Magento logo printed on it

Comment: Like this @Sander?! :) https://twitter.com/LimeSoda_at/status/268744136125976576

Comment: @AnnaVölkl Whaaaaat?! I'm coming over!

Comment: @Sander: Nothing left, we had that 2 years ago :)

Comment: Happy Birthday Magento The Great :-)

Comment: happy birthday :)